# Notepad++ custom syntax highlighting setting - where to look for it?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

Could you tell me where Notepad++ stores custom syntax highlighting settings?

Answer (score 5):

Dependent on your installation configuration, it's either in \Documents and Settings{your profile name}\Application Data\Notepad++\userDefineLang.xml or Notepad++ installation folder\userDefineLang.xml